# Virtual memory management in Fortran under Mac OS X

Tags: arrays, macos, memory-management, fortran, swap

I'm writing a Fortran 90 program (compiled using gfortran) to run under Mac OS X.  I have 13 data arrays, each comprising about 0.6 GB of data  My machine is maxed out at 8 GB real memory, and if I try to hold all 13 arrays in memory at once, I'm basically trying to use all 8 GB, which I know isn't possible in view of other system demands.   So I know that the arrays would be subject to swapping.  What I DON'T know is how this managed by the operating system.  In particular,

Does the OS swap out entire data structures (e.g., arrays) when it needs to make room for other data structures, or does it rather do it on a page-by-page basis?  That is, does it swap out partial arrays, based on which portions of the array have been least-recently accessed?

The answer may determine how I organize the arrays.  If partial arrays can get swapped out, then I could store everything in one giant array (with indexing to select which of the 13 subarrays I need) and trust the OS to manage everything efficiently.  Otherwise, I might preserve separate and distinct arrays, each one individually fitting comfortably within the available physical memory.

Answer (score 3):

Operating systems are not typically made aware of structures (like arrays) in user memory. Most operating systems I'm aware of, including Mac OS X, swap out memory on a page-by-page basis.

Answer (score 0):

Although the process is often wrongly called *swapping*, on x86 as well as on many modern architectures, the OS performs *paging* to what is still called the swap device (mostly because of historical reasons). The virtual memory space of each process is divided into pages and a special table, called process page table, holds the mapping between pages in virtual memory and frames in physical memory. Each page can be mapped or not mapped. Further mapped pages can be present or not present. Access to an unmapped page results in segmentation fault. Access to a non-present page results in page fault which is further handled by the OS - it takes the page from the swap device and installs it into a frame in the physical memory (if any is available). The standard page size is 4 KiB on x86 and almost any other widespread architecture nowadays. Also, modern MMUs (Memory Management Units, often an integral part of the CPU) support huge pages (e.g. 2 MiB) that can be used to reduce the amount of entries in the page tables and thus leave more memory for user processes.

So paging is really fine grained in comparison with your data structures and one often has loose or no control whatsoever over how the OS does it. Still, most Unices allow you to give instructions and hints to the memory manager using the C API, available in the `<sys/mman.h>` header file. There are functions that allows you to lock a certain portion of memory and prevent the OS from paging it out to the disk. There are functions that allows you to hint the OS that a certain memory access pattern is to be expected so that it can optimise the way it moves pages in and out. You may combine these with clearly developed data structures in order to achieve some control over paging and to get the best performance of a given OS.